# php compare array data

Tags: php, loops, associative-array

I have a CSV file I loop thru to get an array od data that looks like this:

```
    $data[0]['StockNumber']
```

This array as 400 different rows.
I need to compare these values against my database and do 3 action.

Select data from my database and return as an object.

If $data[0]['stockNumber'] exist in my DB, I want to update my database.
If $data[0]['stockNumber'] doesn't exist, I want to add to my database.

After that, if a stock number exist in my DB but not in my CSV, I want to delete from my DB.

How can I loop this?

here is the code I am using

```
        function ImportCSV2Array($filename)
{
    $row = 0;
    $col = 0;

    $handle = @fopen($filename, "r");
    if ($handle) 
    {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096,'|','"')) !== false) 
        {
            if (empty($fields)) 
            {
            $fields = $row;
            continue;
        }

             foreach ($row as $k=>$value) 
            {
            $results[$col][$fields[$k]] = $value;
        }
            $col++;
                unset($row);
        }
        if (!feof($handle)) 
        {
            echo "Error: unexpected fgets() failn";
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return $results;
}

$csvArray = ImportCSV2Array($filename);
print_r($csvArray[4]['StockNumber']);

"SELECT StockNumber FROM my_table"
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Now, how can I check all the valus from $result against value in $results

Comment: writing code would be a good start...

Answer (score 1):

IMO Your approach to solve this task is wrong.

Here's how I would do this.

1- Create a temp table in mysql, parse the CSV file & add the file data into the temp table.

2- Run a single query updating quantities or whatever if the ids exists in the original table.

```
update `original_table` `ot` set `ot`.quantity = `t`.`quantity` 
inner join temp_table `t` on ot.id = t.id
```

3- Run a single query deleting products that does not exists in my temp table

```
delete from `original_table` WHERE `id` NOT IN(SELECT `id` FROM `temp_table`)
```

4- Run a single query adding products that exists in my temp table but not in my original table.

```
eg: INSERT INTO `original_table` (`id`, `name` ...) SELECT `id`, `name` ... FROM `temp_table` WHERE `temp_table`.`id` NOT IN(SELECT `id` FROM `original_table`)
```

This approach your entire process would take a few seconds.

Ofcourse this is just an example, try with local data first to see if everything works fine before putting this into production.

Comment: sounds promissing. I will try that.